# How to start Tokyo tyrant server using ttservctl file

Tags: freebsd, tokyo-cabinet, tokyo-tyrant

i successfully tokyo tyrant and tokyo cabinet now i have to start the tokyo tyrant server when i run the command

./ttservctl start

instead of starting the server it is giving me error and the output is

```
ritesh@ritesh-desktop:~/tokyotyrant-1.1.33$ sudo ./ttservctl start
Starting the server of Tokyo Tyrant
Executing: ttserver -port 1978 -dmn -pid /var/ttserver/pid
./ttservctl: 76: ./ttservctl: ttserver: not found
The server could not started
```

how to resolve this error i am new to tokyo tyrant please guideline!!

Answer (score 1):

you can find the "ttserver" file by using the this simple command and the use the result as as bash command:

```
find / -name ttserver
```

when i used the command it gave me a result like this:

```
/usr/local/tokyotyrant-1.1.33/bin/ttserver
```

Answer (score 0):

`ttservctl` is the shell script used to start/stop/restart the Tokyo Tyrant server (a.k.a startup script). This startup script is just a wrapper around the `ttserver` command-line tool.

Your problem here is that your shell cannot find the `ttserver` tool which is certainly not in your `$PATH`.

It sounds as if:

1. you try to execute the startup script located at the root of the Tokyo Tyrant source code: `./ttservctl`
2. and thus, you have NOT installed Tokyo Tyrant but just built it (i.e `./configure && make`)

You should re-build it and run `make install`: by default it will be installed under `/usr/local` but you can change this at configure time via the `--prefix=/path/to/dest` option.

Once done just hit `ttservctl start` without the `./` and it should work.